# Script task to check if file exists then email

Tags: ssis, file-exists

I've got a simple SSIS package that I want to include a section that determines if the file existed in the folder or not and email out either a fail or pass email. I've tried to use a script task after the main for loop section,and use precedence constraints to email either the file was there or not depending on success or failure. Every time I run it the script it picks up a success flag (File is present) from somewhere, when the file isn't there.

I put a message box output in the script code to show if the file exists variable was set to False or True, and it came up False, as well as on the mail send it shows false for variable value, but is sending a success email.

Iv'e got the following variables in my script task, the FileExist is a boolean variable set at package level to default false. In my script code I am checking if the xlFileName is existing and then setting a flag to print out Y or N

[image: Variables used in Script Task]

The code in the script is as follows:

```
 Public Sub Main()
        Dim fileExists As String
        fileExists = CType(File.Exists(Dts.Variables("User::xlFileName").Value.ToString()), String)
      
        If fileExists = "False" Then
            MessageBox.Show("N")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Y")
           
        End If

    End Sub
```

Do I need to set the ScriptResult in the code to success/Failure, depending on outcome?

```
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

I tried this earlier and the script task just failed.

In the precedence constraints (Set to Evaluate Operation: Expression) I also had the following but removed them as they were not making any difference, but tested ok.

```
@[User::FileExists]="False"    - For No File
@[User::FileExists]="True"     - For File Present
```

I'm not a regular user of ssis, nor have I used script tasks as far back as I can remember, so be kind!

Thanks

Andrew

Edit: Precedent Constraint settings images below. I've now got these set to check the variable for true/false depending on if file is present or not:

[image: Success]

[image: Failure]

Changed the variable to populate with True as a Boolean rather than a string value, and set taskresult to Success/Failure.

```
Public Sub Main()
        Dim fileExists As Boolean
        fileExists = CType(File.Exists(Dts.Variables("User::xlFileName").Value.ToString()), Boolean)
       
        If fileExists = False Then
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
            Dts.Variables("User::FileExists").Value = False

        Else
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
            Dts.Variables("User::FileExists").Value = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

When I run the script and the file is not available the script task fails but sends the mail as if success:

[image: Script firing Result Succcess and Script fail]

Comment: can you show us the flow ? the precedence constraint ?

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh I have added the precedent constraint settings at the end of my original post.